# Same height for all images in the slider without destroying the images

Tags: jquery, html, css

When you go to [this site](http://goo.gl/drKFnE), you will see that the images on the slider (in the header) have different heights. I tried this code to use the same height for all images:

```
.carousel .slider img { 
    max-height: 600px
}
```

This works but then I have the problem that the images are distorted.

Is there a way to fix this issue, somehow like cutting the image when the height is higher than 600px or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the same width and height for all images you can use something like this:

```
<div id="slider">
    <img src="http://ragazzon-schweiz.your-click.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/rag-golf-141218-9926-edit.jpg">
</div>

#slider{
    height:600px;
    max-height:600px;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#slider img{
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add the width the the img tag itself and the browser will make it the correct proportional height:

```
<img src="img.png" width=200 />
```